# How to implement view and url patterns for Post and Category models in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-3.0

I'm trying to learn Django by building a simple blog. I have three models: Post, Category, and Tag.

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_STATUS, default=0)
    visibility = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_VISIBILITY, default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    excerpt = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Tag')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on', 'title']
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name = 'Tag'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tags'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have two views - posts_index shows all the posts, and single should show a single post.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Category, Tag


def posts_index(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': all_posts})


def single(request, slug, category):
    single_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'single.html', {'single': single_post, 'category_slug': single_post.slug})
```

In mu urls.py I have the following configuration:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.posts_index, name='index'),
        path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug>/', views.single, name='single')
]
```

I added several categories (General, Sports...) and their slugs are same as titles but lowercase i.e. general, sports.

I want to achieve that when I click on a post title on my index page (I already have that sorted out in templates) that I am transferred to a single blog post page with a url that looks like this: example.com/category-slug/my-post-slug

Currently, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /general/test-post-we-hope-best/

single() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/general/test-post-we-hope-best/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

single() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'

Exception Location:     /Users/XXXXX/XXXXXXX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 113
```

This is the index.html template that looks and work fine, but when I click on links it throws an error i pasted above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <a href="{% url 'single' post.category.slug post.slug%}"><h2>{{post.title}}</h2></a>
        <p>Posted in: {{post.category}}, Posted by: {{post.author}}</p>
        <img height="120px" width="120px" src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="{{post.title}}">
        <p>{{post.excerpt}}</p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stuck on this one for a while now.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `category_slug` used for? When you do a lookup in your `single` view, you are only looking up by `slug`.

Comment: `category_slug` should return stuff like "general" or "sports" and then the URL should look something like example.com/sports/my-post-for-the-sports-category.

When I just get a `slug` from the single - it's the Post slug (my-post-for-the-sports-category), not a Category slug which contains my Post.

Comment: But you are only querying by the single slug - your view has no way of knowing which category the post falls under, unless you tell it. Perhaps you meant your URL to be `path('<category_slug>/<slug>/', views.single, name='single')`, and your view `get` to be `Post.objects.get(slug=slug, category=Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)`?

Comment: Hm... I made changes to my single function and it now looks as per your suggestion:

`def single(request, slug, category):
    single_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug, category=Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug))
    return render(request, 'single.html', {'single': single_post})`

But now I'm getting the (same) following error: 

TypeError at /general/test-post-we-hope-best/

single() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'

Not sure how my view function should look now, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% url 'single' post_id %}
```

and if you have two slugs

```
{% url 'single' post_id, another_id %}
```

Will do that for you, but I suggest to change the url name for something like post_details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what concerns me - template renders it nicely - I am having problem fetching the Category slug of a Post (trying to get the Category slug of the category to which this post belongs to) and then passing that to path function.

Comment: post.category.slug  will give you the category slug

Comment: Yes, I already have that as stated above `"{% url 'single' post.category.slug post.slug%}"` - my issue is that when I click on a URL generated that way, I'm not sent to the single blog page/detail page. That's what causing me troubles.

Answer (score 0):

There - I was able to figure it out myself, here's the view function now:

```
def single(request, slug, category_slug=None):
    single_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    return render(request, 'single.html', {'single': single_post, 'category_slug':category_slug})
```

And in your url.py you simply pass it as an argument like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.posts_index, name='index'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug>/', views.single, name='single')
]
```